# Setting up coordinate system in Map Tiler

Tags: objective-c, ios7, gis, openstreetmap, maptiler

I am creating Map tiles based on Map Image using Map Tiler software.

- Now in that as a first step i selected Map Image from system.
- Than i have to set the coordinate system for that i have following options :

**See this image:**

[image]

- I choose second option from it. that is **WGS84 - Latitude and longitude (EPSG:4326)**
- In that i have this type of algo to fill up with the coordinate values :

> GEOGCS["WGS 84", DATUM["WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137,
>   298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0], AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
>   AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
>   AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]], AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

But its not working for me. The tiles are creating well but when i am trying to create the database using Map2Sqlite software than it takes always static lat-long although i specified the Lat-Long of particular region.

- Can anyone suggest which of the option mentioned in above Image should i choose ?
- Also if there is any alternate way to create tiles & convert it to Sq Lite db than please suggest me.

As i checked map2sqlite is working well. But when i create tiles at that time passing the coordinates is somewhere wrong.

So anyone can please suggest me while creating tiles from Map image how to pass Coordinates of our region.

Any suggestions or hints will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJxdCe9CNYg

It shows a step by step guide how to overlay an image on top of Google Maps or OpenStreetMap.

MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com/) generates tiles compatible with the popular global mercator system automatically - these are compatible with most of the API and SDKs.